# hive installation error with cygwin windows

Tags: windows, hive, cygwin

I Got the error below whilst installing  hive followed below instruction 
Hive 1.2.1 and hadoop 1.2.1

Defined HADOOP_HOME and java_home

Executed :

```
bin/hive -hiveconf java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:637)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 0.20.2
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:139)
        at   org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.j`enter code here`ava:368)
```

Any help solving or understanding this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Java is not a cygwin program. So likely the`tmpdir=/tmp` and similar are not correct.

Comment: I used this link for installation. http://xuzhaotech.blogspot.com/2013/01/installing-hive-on-windows.html.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, but on Linux. There were only 3 available results on Googling, so mentioning how I solved it:

This could a compatibility issue of Java JDK and Hadoop and Hive. I tried a couple of things like trying different Hive versions. What worked was downgrading jdk from 11 to 8 and then installing hive, especially the version 2.3.9.

Then it started working. Hope this helps.